# Execution of a file

Tags: compiling

How to execute a `makefile`? This file is contained in the sts-2.1.2 file downloadable from [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html):

According to the NIST documentation (section 5.3), I need to edit the `makefile`.

> Modify the following lines:
>   (a) CC(your ANSI C compiler)
>   (b) ROOTDIR (the root directory that was prescribed earlier in the process, e.g.,
>   rng/)

```
user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ ./makefile
./makefile: line 1: CC: command not found
./makefile: line 2: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 3: ROOTDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 4: ROOTDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 4: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 5: ROOTDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 5: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 6: VPATH: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
 ......
```

There are 94 lines in total.

Then, I did as you said:

```
 user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ make makefile
 make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'.
 user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ ls
 data  experiments  include  makefile  makefile~  obj  src  templates

 user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ make  makefile
 make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'.
```

Comment: According to which documentation? Did you edit as this document suggested?

Comment: According to this document (section:5.3) http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/SP800-22rev1a.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `make` to run a Makefile. This assumes that you're in the same directory as where the file `Makefile` is located.

If you're in a different directory, run `make -C directory`, where `directory` is the path to the directory that contains the file `Makefile`.

Comment: the terminal outputs that  nothing to be done for 'makefile'

Comment: Please add more points to my reputation so that I can insert an image to show the output.

Comment: @user3080956: You can copy text from the terminal window. Select the region you want to copy, right-click, and select Copy.

Comment: user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ ./makefile
./makefile: line 1: CC: command not found
./makefile: line 2: GCCFLAGS: command not found

./makefile: line 94: rebuild:: command not found
user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ make makefile
make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'.

Comment: When adding command prompt output, you should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/638848/edit) your question instead. That way formatting is preserved.

Comment: Because the makefile is not correctly named (it should be `Makefile`, not `makefile`, and file names are case-sensitive), run `make -F makefile` instead. Don't attempt to run it as a regular script.

Comment: @saiarcot895 actually the switch is lower-case `-f` and lower-case `makefile` is fine: to quote the man page *If no -f option is  present, make  will  look for the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile, in that order.*

Comment: @user3080956: In that case, just run `make`; don't have anything after that.

Comment: No problem: the important thing is to run **either** plain `make` (which will find the default `makefile` or `Makefile`) **or** `make -f makefile` but **not** `make makefile` which tries to *build a target called* makefile

Comment: @saiarcot895 This is what I get:
       user@SC13-VM:~/Documents/sts-2.1.2$ make  makefile
     make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'.

Comment: @user3080956: See steeldriver's comment above. Do **NOT** run `make makefile`; instead, run `make`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thank you very much, finally it executed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the comments of the above answer, you might have done the same mistake as I did:

Wrong command: `make makefile`
This will give you that error "There's nothing to make"

Right command: `make -f makefile`

I should mention that I already made it an executable file and encountered the same host of errors. Also, the aforementioned command executed without errors at first, but the `assess` file did not appear as promised. I repeated it and it worked. I am a novice so I really can't comment on that much.